# Using Autofac and multiple WithMetadata assignments

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, autofac

I am trying to use Autofac specifying 2 metadata items.  It seems to add these fine, however, I am not too clear on how to retrieve the service by specifying both of these items.  I have metadata items for an Assembly Name and a Version.  The registration snippet is as follows:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).Where(
t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => 
plugin.Interface == i.Name)).As<IPlugin>()
.WithMetadata<IMetaDataName>(m => m.For(pn => pn.Name, name)
.WithMetadata<IMetaDataVersion>(m => m.For(pn => pn.Version, version)
```

The only documentation and examples I can find specify that I can use this syntax:

```
IEnumerable<Lazy<IPlugin, IMetaDataName>>
```

in the costructor of the class or in a class that resolves the service I am after.  What I am after is a mechanism to let me do the following:

```
Get the service that has the MetaDataName == "Service1" AND MetaDataVersion == "1.4"
```

Currently I have concatenated the two together for 1 metadata type which works but feels clunky.  Is there are better approach to this?

Thanks

Craig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than concatenate both interfaces into one, you can just create a separate concatenated interface for the importer.

The interface name used at registration time doesn't have to match the one used as a dependency - the property names are the only shared information at this point.

The metadata view type used in a dependency is really specific to the class *receiving* the dependency rather than the type providing it, so these can vary independently.

Know this isn't exactly the answer you were looking for but hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thanks for your response.  What I have ended up doing is concatenated the string for Name and Version into one property of the metadata interface (format Name_Version) and used as the dependency in the constructor of the receiver.  It works, and I need to continue with the project, but I might revisit this later to see if I can make it closer to what I want.  Thanks for all your work on Autofac, it's great!